# Can I say: Be/ have/ do a BBA in Finance

Tags: idioms

Can I say: 
I'm a BBA/an MBA.
I have a BBA/an MBA.
I'm doing a BBA/an MBA.

Comment: You can say "I have an MBA". Before then, you can say "I am studying for an MBA".

Answer (score 1):

An MBA is something you *have* not something you *are*,

> My undergraduate degree is from Stanford, and I **have** an MBA from Northwestern.

You can say you are *getting*, *doing*, *going for*, or *working on* an MBA.

> I took a break from working full time to **go for** my MBA.

Otherwise (in the US) I've never heard anyone talk about a BBA.  Most bachelors degrees are not noteworthy enough for special mention.  Instead, when talking about your undergraduate degree you reference your *major* field of study (which can be Business Administration).

> I'm currently at Stanford University, **majoring in** Economics.

(Edit) James K pointed out that, colloquially, "MBA" can mean *"a person with an MBA degree"*, usually from some noteworthy school.  Example:

> The company hired some Harvard **MBAs**

However, I have never heard anyone say, *"I am an MBA."*  I recommend avoiding this colloquial use until you understand its proper context.

Comment: You sometimes hear MBA used for metonymy "The company hired some Harvard MBAs"

Comment: @JamesK  Good point, although I would say that use is *colloquial*.  I've edited my answer.